# how to improve Pre-recognization inside flexicapture(not sdk)

Tags: abbyy

I am new to flexicapture(not sdk).
I am confused by pre-recognization. The static texts and regular expression match keep on failing as pre-recognization fails.

Is there a way to change/improve image settings like contrast when adding them without going through scanning station? (I only found the auto-rotation,despeckle ones)
Also, is there a way to improve or limit the character sets for pre-reorganization? (Like this image won't have character '*', Not select language nor mode)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is always a way. Please upload your problem images.